# Rspec Mail object does not respond to include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to learn testing in rails with the help of this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test). But I get stuck with this step

```
expect(last_email).to include(user.email)
```

The error message is

```
expected #<Mail::Message:47172420, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Sun, 08 Feb 2015 09:51:56 +0530>, <From: from@example.com>, <To: person1@example.com>, <Message-ID: <54d6e464682e_1450a1b32815670@User-PC.mail>>, <Subject: Password Reset>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_54d6e4642e9e_1450a1b328155a"; charset=UTF-8>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit>> to include "person1@example.com", but it does not respond to `include?`
```

The mail object does not respond to 'include?'. Could this be due to a change in the rspec syntax or is it something wrong with the code. Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not calling `to` on `last_email`:

```
expect(last_email.to).to include(user.email)
```